# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when setting a CoreData field (but not other fields) after an async operation

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, asynchronous, automatic-ref-counting

I have a `UserService` singleton that contains the following method. I am getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the line that sets `book.downloaded` in the progress callback.

I want the service to continue to download and update the book object *even if the user exits the view they are on* (currently a detail view for a table). It all works fine if I keep the detail view open, but when I back out to the parent table view, I get the bad access.

My first thought was that `book` is being released by ARC, but that doesn't hold water. You can set other properties, and even read the current value of `book.downloaded`, but the minute you try to set it. Boom.

`Book` is a CoreData class generated by mogenerator, if it matters.

```
// UserService is a singleton. 
// Only errors if I back out of the detail view to the parent table view.
-(void)addBook:(Book *)book downloadProgress:(void (^)(Book *))progressCb downloadComplete:(void (^)(Book *))cb {
    book.purchasedValue = YES;
    book.downloadedValue = 0.0;

    // making my UserService own the book with a strong reference doesn't help
    self.strongBookProperty = book;

    [FileService.shared
        downloadFiles:[FileService.shared byBookId:book.bookId]
        progress:^(float percent) {
            book.title = @"fake title"; // no error!
            NSLog(@"old downloaded %@", book.downloaded); // no error!
            book.downloaded = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:percent]; // EXC_BAD_ACCESS
            progressCb(book);
        }
        complete:^() {
            book.downloaded = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
            cb(book);
        }
    ];
}
```

---

**UPDATE** I am key-value observing `book.downloaded` in the details view that kicks this off. If I comment out the key-value observation it doesn't error. Why? (Obviously this makes my view not update). This explains why only that property was throwing an error (it's the only one being key-value observed).

Comment: How is downloaded defined?

Comment: In my core data model file, it's a property set to "float". In Book.m it's defined as `@dynamic downloaded;`

Comment: It should be NSNumber.

Comment: Wait, what? It is, in Book.h `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber* downloaded;`

Comment: Sounds like you should post your KVO code.

Comment: Why are you downvoting/voting to close the question? I had no idea it was a KVO problem when I posted the question, and it might help someone who is experiencing the same thing.

Comment: seemed like a perfectly good question and answer to me.  +1 from me unless someone can explain the -1/close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not removing my key-value observers on book in the `dealloc` method of my details view. The following got rid of the error. (In the details view)

```
-(void)dealloc {
    [self.book removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"downloaded"];
    [self.book removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"purchased"];
}
```

I thought ARC would take care of that for me, but I it sort of makes sense that it wouldn't know how. I also don't really understand how that would cause a bad access on the line I was getting it. It seems like it would give a bad access in the dealloced observer instead.